# Printing an array on the Console

Tags: c#, arrays

I wanna have a function which return a array. I test this first with a void-function, but the string in the console is empty and I didn't find my vault.

```
private void getValueOfRadio() {
  string[,] arrayUrl = new String[4, 3] {
    { "xx0",       "xxx0",    "xxxx0" },
    { "xx1",       "xxx1",    "xxxx1" },
    { "xx2",       "xxx2",    "xxxx2" },
    { "xx3",       "xxx3",    "xxxx3" }
  };

  var checkedRadioButton = groupUrl
    .Controls
    .OfType<RadioButton>()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked == true);

  int i = 0;
  if (checkedRadioButton != null) {
    switch (checkedRadioButton.Text) {
      case "MK-Live":
        i = 1;
        break;
      case "MK-Test":
        i = 2;
        break;
      case "Roland Test":
        i = 3;
        break;
      default:
        i = 0;
        break;
      }
    }

    string[] returnArray = new string[] { 
      arrayUrl[i, 0], arrayUrl[i, 1], arrayUrl[i, 2] };

    Console.WriteLine(returnArray);
  }
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see what your code is doing with the current data?

Comment: i got only System.String[] in the Console. No Error, but this empty String.

Comment: You need to print the CONTENT of the array - your code is printing out the type of the variable.

Comment: Use `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", returnArray));`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: there is no `ToString()` method for the array that can print the elements directly. Use the suggestion from @AleksAndreev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's *extract* some methods: `RowIndexFromButton` - which row (based on radiobuttons) we want to print and `RowFromArray` - extracting row from 2d array.

```
   private int RowIndexFromButton() {
     var checkedRadioButton = groupUrl
       .Controls
       .OfType<RadioButton>()
       .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Checked);

     if (checkedRadioButton == null)
       return -1; //TODO: or 0 if we want to get 0th record

     switch (checkedRadioButton.Text) { 
       case "MK-Live":
         return 1;
       case "MK-Test":
         return 2;
       case "Roland Test":
         return 3;
       default:
         return 0;
     }
   }

   private static IEnumerable<T> RowFromArray<T>(T[,] array, int row) {
     if (null == array)
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
     else if (row < array.GetLowerBound(0) || row > array.GetUpperBound(0))
       yield break;

     for (int i = array.GetLowerBound(1); i <= array.GetUpperBound(1); ++i)
       yield return array[row, i];
   }
```

Then we can easily combine both methods together:

> I wanna have a function which return a array

```
   private T[] RowFromButton<T>(T[,] array) {
     return RowFromArray(array, RowIndexFromButton()).ToArray();
   }
```

And use it:

```
   string[,] arrayUrl = new String[4, 3] {
     { "xx0", "xxx0", "xxxx0" },
     { "xx1", "xxx1", "xxxx1" },
     { "xx2", "xxx2", "xxxx2" },
     { "xx3", "xxx3", "xxxx3" }
   };

   string[] returnArray = RowFromButton(arrayUrl); 

   // When printing collection (array) we should join items (e.g. with space)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", returnArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

About `Console.WriteLine Method`, there are a few of overloads such as:

> **WriteLine(String)**
>   Writes the specified string value, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.
>
> **WriteLine(Char[])**
>   Writes the specified array of Unicode characters, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.
>
> **WriteLine(Object)**
>   the current line terminator, to the standard output stream.Writes the text representation of the specified object, followed by current line terminator, to the standard output stream.
>
> **...**

Since there is no overload such as `WriteLine(String[])`, we
can use `WriteLine(String)` to print `string[]`, like

- use `foreach` to print string item one by one
- `string.Join` items in string array to one string and then print it out

Code snippet in the post,

```
string[] returnArray = new string[] { arrayUrl[i, 0], arrayUrl[i, 1], arrayUrl[i, 2] };

// Console.WriteLine(returnArray); // <-- the original code
foreach(var s in returnArray) {
   Console.WriteLine(s); 
}

//or
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", returnArray));
```

Some follow up,

```
char[] cArray = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'};
Console.WriteLine(cArray); // prints "abc"
```

That's because there is one overload `WriteLine(Char[])` to print `Char[]`